# How can I display FireMonkey modal form from a DLL?

Tags: delphi, dll, firemonkey

I would like to load a DLL (from an VCL application <s>but that should't be important</s> [that is not true as both VCL and FMX contain a message loop]) and display a FireMonkey modal form created in that DLL. Showing the form works OK but I have problems cleaning after it ...

I can only find only articles on that topic from years 2011/2012 and they mostly refer to XE2. These solutions sadly don't work anymore. (Or I'm doing something wrong.)

All sample files are here: https://github.com/gabr42/GpDelphiCode/tree/master/FMX%20from%20DLL

My DLL just exports `ShowMainForm`.

```
library FMXDLL;

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  FMXMain in 'FMXMain.pas' {FormMain};

{$R *.res}

exports
  ShowMainForm;

begin
end.
```

`ShowMainForm` initializes GDI+ and then shows the form. Afterwards, it tries to clean up but fails at that.

```
uses
  Winapi.GDIPAPI,
  Winapi.GDIPOBJ;

procedure InitGDIP;
begin
  // Initialize StartupInput structure
  StartupInput.DebugEventCallback := nil;
  StartupInput.SuppressBackgroundThread := False;
  StartupInput.SuppressExternalCodecs   := False;
  StartupInput.GdiplusVersion := 1;

  GdiplusStartup(gdiplusToken, @StartupInput, nil);
end;

procedure FreeGDIP;
begin
  if Assigned(GenericSansSerifFontFamily) then
    GenericSansSerifFontFamily.Free;
  if Assigned(GenericSerifFontFamily) then
    GenericSerifFontFamily.Free;
  if Assigned(GenericMonospaceFontFamily) then
    GenericMonospaceFontFamily.Free;
  if Assigned(GenericTypographicStringFormatBuffer) then
    GenericTypographicStringFormatBuffer.free;
  if Assigned(GenericDefaultStringFormatBuffer) then
    GenericDefaultStringFormatBuffer.Free;

  GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
end;

procedure ShowMainForm; stdcall;
var
  FormMain: TFormMain;
begin
  InitGDIP;
  Application.Title := 'DLL Form';
  FormMain := TFormMain.Create(Application);
  FormMain.ShowModal;
  FormMain.Free;
  Application.Terminate;
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  FreeGDIP;
end;
```

Form contains a button which closes the form.

```
procedure TFormMain.btnCloseClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;
```

Host application loads this DLL when its main form is created

```
procedure TFormHost.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FLibHandle := LoadLibrary('FMXDLL');
  if FLibHandle = 0 then begin
    ShowMessage('Cannot load FMXDLL.DLL');
    Application.Terminate;
  end
  else begin
    FShowMain := GetProcAddress(FLibHandle, 'ShowMainForm');
    if not assigned(FShowMain) then begin
      ShowMessage('Missing export: ShowMainForm');
      Application.Terminate;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

It has a button which shows FireMonkey form.

```
procedure TFormHost.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FShowMain();
end;
```

DLL is unloaded when form is destroyed.

```
procedure TFormHost.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FLibHandle <> 0 then begin
    FreeLibrary(FLibHandle);
    FLibHandle := 0;
  end;
end;
```

This is observed behaviour (Delphi 10.1 Berlin running on Windows 10 Creators Edition):

- I start my host program. An icon with name "DLL Host" appears in the taskbar. [**OK**]
- When I click the button, FireMonkey form appears. [**OK**].
- This new form also has a taskbar button with a name "DLL Form". [**OK**]
- When I click Close button on the FireMonkey form, it closes. [**OK**]
- However, its taskbar button is still visible on screen! [**Definitely NOT OK!**]
- I can click and close FireMonkey form multiple times. It will always show correctly but its taskbar button will never disappear.
- When I close my VCL form, it disappears from the taskbar. [**OK**]
- The FireMonkey form is, however, still visible and program hangs. [**Definitely NOT OK!**] Stack shows that the code is somewhere inside `d3d11.dll`, if that can be trusted.

I tried different ways of creating and destroying the FMX form but nothing seems to be working correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: FMX to FMX using packages is fine. Outside of that your first issue is solvable, without source code changes, however the crashing one isn't, if GDI+ is really needed.

Longer answer: you can fix the extraneous taskbar button easily enough by calling `RegisterApplicationHWNDProc` from `FMX.Platform.Win`, and providing a callback function; this function should then return a HWND sourced from the host. Best way to do this is probably to export an explicit initialisation function:

```
var
  _AppHandle: HWND;

function GetAppHandle: HWND;
begin
  Result := _AppHandle;
end;

function InitializeDLL(AppHandle: HWND): HRESULT; stdcall;
begin
  try
    if AppHandle = 0 then Exit(E_HANDLE);
    if _AppHandle <> 0 then Exit(E_FAIL);
    InitGDIP; //reuse what you've taken from WinApi.GDIOBJ.pas
    _AppHandle := AppHandle;
    RegisterApplicationHWNDProc(GetAppHandle);
    Result := S_OK;
  except
    Result := E_UNEXPECTED;
  end;
end;
```

You'd then have a `FinalizeDLL` export or somesuch for cleanup:

```
procedure FinalizeDLL; stdcall;
begin
  FreeGDIP;
end;
```

The host would call `InitializeDLL` on first-time use; were the application itself use FMX, then it should pass `ApplicationHWND` from `FMX.Platform.Win` for this.

However, this doesn't resolve the crashes on close. More exactly: I don't get them when the DLL is using the Direct2D backend, only when I force GDI+. The problem is the existence of resources held globally, e.g. by the style manager. You might think you could clean things up explicitly before finalising GDI+ by doing what the private `FinalizeForms` procedure in `FMX.Forms.pas` does (while `FinalizeForms` itself is private, what it calls is not):

```
//from FMX.Forms
procedure FinalizeForms;
begin
  FreeControls;
  TStyleManager.UnInitialize;
  TFilterManager.UnInitialize;
  TBitmapCodecManager.UnInitialize;
  TTextLayoutManager.UnInitialize;
  TCanvasManager.UnInitialize;
  TContextManager.UnInitialize;
  TShaderManager.UnInitialize;
end;

procedure FinalizeDLL; stdcall;
begin
  FinalizeForms;
  FreeGDIP;
end;
```

This workaround however still fails eventually because `TStyleManager.UnInitialize` uses a plain `Free` for its first two disposals (the third gets the `FreeAndNil` treatment), which obviously then leads to access violations when the 'real' `FinalizeForms` is called from the finalisation section of `FMX.Forms`.